# MAUI Blazor user registration through Web API

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi, maui-blazor

I have gotten to the point where I don't know how to perform user registration in .NET MAUI Blazor app. I'm using ASP.NET Core API (through Kiota client) for /login endpoint, but I would like to create /registration endpoint which also sends the email confirmation link to the user.

The only way I managed to wrap it in my head is to create an /email-confirmation API endpoint also, but that would leave the user with a bare text API response on an unknown URL after clicking the confirmation link in the email client.

Also, the user can click the confirmation link on any device, so no use in forwarding to myapp://

I'm struggling with little documentation on the topic.